# How to execute SQL in a PowerShell script as part of a Visual Studio Team Services build task?

Tags: azure-pipelines, sqlcmd, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-build-task, invoke-sqlcmd

How to execute SQL against an Azure SQL database as part of a PowerShell script in a VSTS build task in a hosted agent?

There are many tasks available for build definitions: we can execute a PowerShell script

[image]

or deploy SQL using DACPAC or SQLCMD

[image]

or even execute PowerShell on remote machines

[image]

but how to simply execute SQL as part of a PowerShell script?
Invoke-Sqlcmd isn't available as part of the 'Azure PowerShell' task.

I guess it would be possible to remote desktop to an app service, install the SQL Server related bits there and use 'PowerShell on Target Machines' but I feel there has to be a simpler way - perhaps I'm just missing something obvious

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent? Is your SQL server an on-prem SQL instance or an Azure SQL instance?

Comment: Hosted agent and Azure SQL Database. Updated the question as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Azure SQL Database Deployment task, there are SQL Script File and Inline SQL Script types.

[image]

Note: You can use Hosted agent, but not Hosted VS 2017 agent.

Comment: Our SQL batch scripts must be executed from a custom PowerShell script; This is used for versioning the database. It should be also able to exit on error which is possible at least via Invoke-Sqlcmd

Comment: @thomius Using Hosted agent instead (not hosted vs2017), then you can call Invoke-SqlCmd in PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1):

> but how to simply execute SQL as part of a PowerShell script?
>   Invoke-Sqlcmd isn't available as part of the 'Azure PowerShell' task.

I think we can use this PowerShell script to run SQL with Azure Powershell for Azure SQL database:

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=jasontest321.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=jasonsql;User ID=jason;Password='password';Connection Timeout=90"
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$query = "insert into test1 values (3) ; ;" 
$command = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
$connection.Open()
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$connection.Close()
```

Here is my test:

[image]

Also we can use Azure portal **Query editor** to query the table, like this:

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to stop on error? We are doing patching which includes schema updates separated by GO statements (and logic like "if current version not supported then error / exit)

Comment: Do you mean use powershell to achieve the logic? yes, we can use PowerShell to check the version and run that script.

Comment: @thomius Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Yea - thanks, you described how best to execute SQL via PowerShell - starain-MSFT also mentioned the way to tweak Invoke-Sqlcmd into the process (using Hosted instead of Hosted VS2017). Now I'm running two separate processes (one for SQL patching, another for code building and deployment) - anyways, with that said things seem to work like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-SqlCmd becomes available after you run:

```bsh
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force
```

Tested on `windows-2019` and `ubuntu-18.04` (latest at this time).